# Update MYSQL table with values from other tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

tbl1:

```
CC  GG   GA   VALUE
01 NULL NULL  10
02 NULL NULL  22
01 NULL NULL  04
03 NULL NULL  04
```

tbl2:

```
CC GG GA
01 aa xx
02 bb yy
03 cc zz
```

How can I update table 1 GG and GA values from tbl 2, linking by CC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
UPDATE tbl1,tbl2
SET tbl1.GG = tbl2.GG, tbl1.GA = tbl2.GA
WHERE tbl1.CC = tbl2.CC
```

I think its pretty self explanatory - but it updates `tbl1.GG` to `tbl2.GG` and `tbl1.GA` to `tbl2.GA` where `tbl1.CC` equals `tbl2.CC`